# Where can I download Windows 7 x64 Polish ISOs?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

I've recently bought an SSD drive and I want to reinstall Windows 7, but my notebook (ASUS K73SV) didn't come with a Windows 7 DVD, but a recovery partition on HDD. It's okay, but it comes with too much bloatware. I want to reinstall from a clean ISO, but there's the problem...

There are no Polish ISOs.

Digital River holds most ISOs, but not Polish (at least I wasn't able to find one). I don't have a TechNet/MSDN subscription, so I can't download it from there. Even torrents won't lend me a legit ISO. Is there any other place I can try to download from, without buying a key from Microsoft or TechNet subscription? I need exactly Windows 7 Home Premium x64 Polish ISO.

Or, if someone has a TechNet subscription, he could get me a direct download link from there, they're available as long as someone is a subscriber.

Comment: Which files are on the recovery partition? With some (or rather, a lot) of luck those contain the files needed to make a bootable pen drive rather than just a disk image.

Comment: What about contacting the seller or the manufacturer?

Comment: I can't check this (partiton content) for some reason. GParted says about 15GB is used on this partition (25GB, FAT32), and Windows cannot mount this partition at all, I must format it first (definitely not what I want to do). OEM will just give me bloated Recovery disks, and this process takes sometimes months in Poland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't think you can

> Unfortunately, none exist, if you need to work in Polish, you will
>   either need to purchase a localized version of Windows 7 in your
>   native language or consider doing an Anytime Upgrade to Windows 7
>   Ultimate then download the Polish language through Windows Update.

If it came already installed, I think you need to contact the OEM direct

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/where-can-i-dowland-windows-7-64-bit-polish/da82409d-880b-40ce-b4ce-c35609459f8a?msgId=cea161a1-1d1a-4cc9-9443-dda46bd16697)